# Way to remove/ignore last entry in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I use a multifile uploader thats easy to use for end users, but there is a issue it always adds a extra field to allow user to select more files from different folders.

The issue now is that it will produce this

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1450282558_circle-next-arrow-disclosure-glyph.png
                    [1] => 40525882_ml.jpg
                    [2] => pdf-sample.pdf
                    [3] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => application/pdf
                    [3] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpovbkoC
                    [1] => /tmp/phpNCISaS
                    [2] => /tmp/phpuRKS37
                    [3] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 405
                    [1] => 218829
                    [2] => 7945
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

The last entry in every part is empty, is there a way I can get around this? I want to remove/ignore lets say [3] under name, type etc. so I avoid that empty entry?

Comment: fix the form that crates the extra empty field. cure the disease not the symptom

Comment: I think array_filter() with strlen() should help?

Comment: it doesn't look empty for the 'error' key, maybe it's a reserved field just for this case?

Comment: assuming a loop just do an `if empty();`

Comment: Its a field thats created so the user can uploade more files from different places on there computer, the downside is it adds an extra empty field to do this.

But got a greate answer so now i can work with it and actually do a solution based on the jquery.filer so thats nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/fa/function.array-slice.php) for this. If your array is stored in *$data*, it works like this:

```
foreach($data["files"] as $attr => $file) {
    $data["files"][$attr] = array_slice($data["files"][$attr], 0, -1);
}

print_r ($data);
```

Or with the use of the by-reference operator (`&`), it can be done shorter:

```
foreach($data["files"] as &$file) {
    $file = array_slice($file, 0, -1);
}
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1450282558_circle-next-arrow-disclosure-glyph.png
                    [1] => 40525882_ml.jpg
                    [2] => pdf-sample.pdf
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => application/pdf
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpovbkoC
                    [1] => /tmp/phpNCISaS
                    [2] => /tmp/phpuRKS37
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 405
                    [1] => 218829
                    [2] => 7945
                )

        )

)
```

The call to array_slice has these arguments:

- the array from which to take the slice (i.e. sub-array);
- the index from where the slice starts: we specify 0;
- the length of the slice. -1 takes everything except the last element.

Comment: saved my day! Sweet just sweet cant say anything else!

Comment: You're welcome, I added a shorter version, which makes use of the by-reference `&` syntax.